# Hyperledger Composer REST server GET API -SKIP,LIMIT

Tags: hyperledger-composer

In Hyperledger Composer REST server, I have already fiter with where query like this

{"where":{ "email": "fsd"}}

http://IP:PORT/api/com.projectname.employee?filter=%7B%22where%22%3A%7B%20%22email%22%3A%20%22fsd%22%7D%7D

But I tried like this

{"limit":"1", "skip":"2"}

Not working. How to get data using skip and limit

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for limit and skip were removed as these options will never be supported by hyperledger fabric. So unfortunately although no error is thrown about the use of limit and skip, they are ignored by hyperledger fabric.

Comment: Not working?.query Q18 {
    description: "Select all drivers aged older than PARAM"
    statement:
        SELECT org.acme.Driver
            WHERE (_$ageParam < age)
                ORDER BY [lastName ASC, firstName DESC]
                    LIMIT _$limitParam
                        SKIP _$skipParam
}

Comment: LIMIT and SKIP are not honoured and hyperledger fabric ignores them even on a direct mango query in fabric chaincode. You cannot use LIMIT or SKIP.

Comment: Hi david, 

query Q18 {
    description: "Select all drivers who has the following interests"
    statement:
        SELECT org.example.Driver
            WHERE (badges CONTAINS [_$search])
}
But not working. Pls help

Comment: query getProductListBySearch {
    description: "Get product list by search text"
    statement:
        SELECT com.augusta.ahc.business.Product
        WHERE (name CONTAINS _$name)
}

Comment: Above mentioned query I sent prodcut name. data return empty values
http://192.168.1.149:3003/api/queries/getProductListBySearch?name=updatedagain
[] PLS HELP